# Is there a function that will allow me to store a specific list(or header) from a csv file in a variable?

Tags: python, cs50

```
def main():

    # TODO: Check for command-line usage
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage : python dna.py (DNA) (SEQUENCE)")
        exit (1)

    file = open(sys.argv[2], "r")
    system = file.read()
    csvfile = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
    truecsv = csv.reader(csvfile)
    dictreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)  #in case I need this
    copydict_ = dictreader
    header = next(truecsv)
    matches = {}
    for i in header[1:len(header)]:
        number = longest_match(system, i)
        match = {i : longest_match(system, i)}
        matches.update(match)
    print(matches)
```

I store the header in a header variable using the next function, but that messes up with the dictionary that is created later by dictreader, which is not ideal as I want to try and MATCH my dict matches with the file. I want to know how I can store the header without using the next function.

Comment: why not take header and then make dict_reader?

Comment: or even consider a more suitable library like `pandas` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
variable = df['COLUMN']
```

This saves an entire column into a variable.

If you want to save the first rows into a variable:

```
variable = df.head(10)
print("First 10 rows of the DataFrame:")
print(variable)
```

If you want to extract specific columns into a variable:

```
variable = df[1:3,]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
row = list(truecsv)
```

this function helps break it into rows, so I can call the header by using row[0]
looking for "rows" instead of lists on google netted me this answer.

Comment: This will create a list and blow up if there are many lines in csv.Using next is safer.